# TouchableNativeFeedbackSafe.SelectableBackgroundBorderless is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, exponentjs

I am trying to use [@exponent/react-native-touchable-native-feedback-safe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@exponent/react-native-touchable-native-feedback-safe) in my react-native based app. I can't seem to set background prop without upsetting either ios or android. 
I did:

```
<TouchableNativeFeedbackSafe onPress={this.props.onPress}
    background={TouchableNativeFeedbackSafe.SelectableBackgroundBorderless()}>
```

this works on android but gives error on iOS: SelectableBackgroundBorderless is not a function.

If I change it from `TouchableNativeFeedbackSafe.SelectableBackgroundBorderless()` to `TouchableNativeFeedbackSafe.SelectableBackgroundBorderless` then iOS works but android throws error:

```
Error while updating property 'nativeBackgroundAndroid' of a view managed by: RCTView
updateViewProp
    ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:89
setProperty
    ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:123
updateProps
    ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:42
updateProperties
    ViewManager.java:36
createView
    NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:227
execute
   UIViewOperationQueue.java:148
dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations
   UIViewOperationQueue.java:890
doFrameGuarded
   UIViewOperationQueue.java:863
doFrame
   GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.java:32
doFrame
   ReactChoreographer.java:131
run
   Choreographer.java:872
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is a typo in the expo package. Someone forked it and corrected it already: https://github.com/netbeast/react-native-touchable-native-feedback-safe
However, I don't think they sent a pull request because the original code isn't publicly available anywhere.

EDIT:

```
TouchableNativeFeedbackSafe.SelectableBackgroundBorderless()
```

is the correct way to go with the package mentioned above.

Comment: I did eventually figure that out, but forgot to answer my own question. Thanks for putting it here.

Comment: I just contacted the author and he fixed it and published version 1.1.2. The code is on GitHub too now https://github.com/expo/react-native-touchable-native-feedback-safe